# How to create a pivot table in Postgresql using case when?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, pivot-table

I want to create a pivot table using postgresql. I could accomplish this using SQLite, and I thought the logic would be similar, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Here's the sample table:

```
create table df(
  campaign varchar(50),
date date not null,
revenue integer not null
);

insert into df(campaign,date,revenue) values('A','2019-01-01',10000);
insert into df(campaign,date,revenue) values('B','2019-01-02',7000);
insert into df(campaign,date,revenue) values('A','2018-01-01',5000);
insert into df(campaign,date,revenue) values('B','2018-01-01',3500);
```

here's my sqlite code to transform the tidy data into pivot table:

```
    select 
    sum(case when strftime('%Y', date) = '2019' then revenue else 0 end) as '2019',
    sum(case when strftime('%Y', date) = '2018' then revenue else 0 end) as '2018',
campaign
    from df
group by campaign
```

the result would be like this:

```
2018    2019    campaign
5000    10000   A
3500    7000    B
```

I tried making the similar code using postgres, I will just use the year 2019:

```
select 

sum(case when extract('year' from date) = '2019' then revenue else 0 end) as '2019',
campaign
from df
group by campaign
```

somehow the code doesn't work, I don't understand what's wrong.

```
Query Error: error: syntax error at or near "'2019'"
```

what do I miss here?

db-fiddle link:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f1WjMAAxwSPRvB8BrxECN7/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `strftime()` is used to extract various parts of a date in SQLite, but is not supported by Postgresql.
Use `date_part()`:

```
select campaign,
  sum(case when date_part('year', date) = '2019' then revenue else 0 end) as "2019",
  sum(case when date_part('year', date) = '2018' then revenue else 0 end) as "2018"
from df
group by campaign
```

Or use Postgresql's `FILTER` clause:

```
select campaign,
  sum(revenue) filter (where date_part('year', date) = '2019') as "2019",
  sum(revenue) filter (where date_part('year', date) = '2018') as "2018"
from df
group by campaign
```

Also, don't use single quotes for table/column names.
SQLite allows it but Postgresql does not. 
It accepts only double quotes which is the SQL standard.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5e67167365b697b68413ef3f105070d2).

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you! and thanks for the tips about single/double quote. they seem the source of the problem.